# python threading module: Is overriding run() necessary

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I am reading tutorials to understand multithreading, and everywhere I see people overriding the run method. It is not clear to me [from the doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects)

> This class represents an activity that is run in a separate thread of control. There are two ways to specify the activity: by passing a callable object to the constructor, or by overriding the run() method in a subclass. No other methods (except for the constructor) should be overridden in a subclass. In other words, only override the **init**() and run() methods of this class.
>
> Once a thread object is created, its activity must be started by calling the thread’s start() method. This invokes the run() method in a separate thread of control.**

so how do I create an interface where a user has an option to `doX` or `doY`  in its own separate thread? For example, if run were necessary, will I have to do something like this?

```
class MyCls(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def doX(self):
        while True:
            time.slee(10)
            return 'x'

    def doY(self):
        while True:
            time.slee(10)
            return 'y'

    def run(self, dowhat):
        assert dowhat.lower() in 'xy', "Can only do X or Y"
        return getattr(self,'do'+dowhat.upper())()
```

Usage:

```
o1 = MyCls()
o1.start()
o1.run('x')
#separate thread
o2 = MyCls()
o2.start()
o2.run('y')
```

is there any method to conveniently do `o1.doX()` which would doX() in its own thread?

Comment: Why not have separate subclasses?

Comment: What do you mean *"how"*? Write two `Thread` subclasses, one of which has a `doX` for `run` and the other of which has `doY` for `run`. Then just instantiate and `start` whichever is required.

Answer (score 2):

In this case You don't even need to subclass threading. Simply

```
from threading import Thread 
class Thingy(object):
    @staticmethod
    def doX():
        print ("X")
    @staticmethod
    def doY():
        print ("Y")
worker1 = Thread(target=Thingy.doX).start()
worker2 = Thread(target=Thingy.doY).start()
```

EDIT: 
I think You meant something like generator that does it's calculation in thread each time? Is this what You more or less wanted?

```
from threading import Thread
import time

class Thingy(object):
    def doX(self,  rng):
        for i in range(0, rng):
            worker1 = Thread(target=self.doY)
            worker1.start()
            worker1.join()
            yield self.item

    def doY(self):
        self.item = time.time()

gen = Thingy().doX(5)
print (gen.next(), str(type(gen)))
print (list(gen))
```

results in

```
(1416756265.972083, "<type 'generator'>")
[1416756265.972913, 1416756265.973542, 1416756265.974052, 1416756265.974545]
```

Comment: if doX() is a generator which constantly yields a value, how can I capture those values?

Comment: @yayu, the `Thread` target will be a function or method that iterates the generator.

Comment: I'm not sure what You mean. You want to get values from generator in this new thread or back in your main thread (which would need ipc mechanism) ?

Comment: @brainovergrow for example `def doX(): i=0; while True: i+=1 \n yield i`

Comment: Interprocess Communication (IPC) is for multiprocessing. Threads are all in the same process, sharing the same address space. The main concern is synchronization, such as using a [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html).

Comment: @eryksun so, for example, `Thread(target=lambda x: for i in xrange(x): yield i).start()`?

Comment: @yayu, the target won't be a generator function, because calling it simply returns a generator instance, and it won't be a generator because it's not callable. It needs to be a regular function or method that iterates the generator. BTW, you can't have a compound statement such as a `for` loop in a `lambda` expression.

Answer (score 0):

> so how do I create an interface where a user has an option to doX or doY in its own separate thread?

As you see in docs, they don't support giving args, kwargs in methods **start** and **run**. So please set your paramaters in class's constructor.

When you calling **start**, it starts new Thread and execute function **run** were overridden by you before. If you want to call you function in same thread just call **run**
Also usually developer just set target parameter when iniitializing new Thread instance, you're not supposed to create your own class everytime.